# Error running mongod command in Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, terminal, linux-mint, mongo-shell

I am trying to run the command

```
  mongod --dbpath=data/db
```

When I get this error:

```
  mongod --dbpath=data/db
 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=10161 port=27017 dbpath=data/db 64-bit host=anr   
 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
 [initandlisten] git version: 52fe0d21959e32a5bdbecdc62057db386e4e029c
 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "data/db" }
 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 
 *********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
 *********************************************************************

 , terminating
 dbexit: 
[initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
[initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
[initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
[initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
[initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
[initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
[initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
[initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
dbexit: really exiting now
```

This is my /data/db:

```
.:
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Mar 26 11:24 db

./db:
total 81928
drwxr-xr-x 2 anr anr     4096 Mar 26 16:07 journal
-rw------- 1 anr anr 67108864 Mar 26 16:07 local.0
-rw------- 1 anr anr 16777216 Mar 26 16:07 local.ns
-rwxr-xr-x 1 anr anr        0 Mar 26 16:07 mongod.lock

./db/journal:
total 3145740
-rw------- 1 anr anr 1073741824 Mar 26 16:07 prealloc.0
-rw------- 1 anr anr 1073741824 Mar 25 17:36 prealloc.1
-rw------- 1 anr anr 1073741824 Mar 25 17:36 prealloc.2
```

## UPDATE:

Modified my path to /data/db,this is the error:

```
 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/data/db" }
 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for   
 socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use 
 [initandlisten] now exiting
 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket:   
 0.0.0.0:28017
 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
```

## UPDATE2:

```
 mongodb  10172     1  0 16:11 ?        00:00:27 /usr/bin/mongod --config 
 /etc/mongodb.conf
 anr      10865  5108  0 17:07 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --colour=auto mongod
```

Comment: Try starting mongo using `mongod --dbpath=/data/db`.  Notice the **/** before data/db

Comment: The problem here is you **did not** specify the path **explicitly** as in : `--dbpath=/data/db` So right now it's looking for something "localized" to where you invoked the command

Comment: Like the error message says, there's probably another mongod (or some other process) running on port 27017.  Try running `ps -ef | grep mongod` to check if mongod is already running, and kill that process using `kill <pid>`

Comment: @AnandJayabalan  There are two processes listed above in the post,which one should I kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The--db-path command doesn't use an = sign.  It's just --db-path  for example:

```
mongod --db-path /data/db
```

You might consider using a config file to make things easier.

Depending on your flavor of Linux, you'll need one of these commands to run the Mongod process from a config file:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Note that the location of the conf file can be whereever you want, you just need to make sure the user running Mongod has the appropriate permissions to it.

The config file allows you to specify most of the options you will need to run the process, including the location of the dbpath, the log path, the port and (important) forking the process into it's own background thread.  An example config file might look like this:

```
dbpath = /data/db
logpath = /var/logs/mongo.log
logappend = true
#bind ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 27111
fork = true
rest = true
verbose = true
#auth = true
#noauth = true
```

The 'auth' and 'noauth' are commented out as well as bind just to indicate that those are options you can also set in the config file for Mongod startup.